# Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have SQL Server 2012 Enterprise edition and for security issue I was changed the default port and the Named Pipes is enabled and the shared memory is enabled,

I am trying to run the following :

```
DECLARE @osqlLine varchar(500)

set @osqlLine = 'osql -d master -E -Q "EXEC sp_help_revlogin" -w 300 -o F:\Daily-BackUp\Login-Backup\Logins_BackUp_' + convert(varchar(9),GETDATE(),112) + '.sql'

EXEC xp_cmdshell  @osqlLine
```

and I get this error :

> [SQL Server Native Client 11.0]Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [2].
>
> [SQL Server Native Client 11.0]Login timeout expired
>
> [SQL Server Native Client 11.0]A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online.

The windows firewall is disabled, allow remote connection to this server option is checked

Any idea ?

thanks in advance...
saleh

Comment: Check this link : http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/05/21/sql-server-fix-error-provider-named-pipes-provider-error-40-could-not-open-a-connection-to-sql-server-microsoft-sql-server-error/

Comment: thanks .. but i already checked this link .. all the steps are already done from my side

Comment: This is old, but I ran into a similar issue today in an application. Mine was a network firewall issue (not Windows firewall).  I also made sure to check the credentials.